# Authorize not working for roles using ASP.NET Core 3.1 Identity with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-identity, mongodb-.net-driver

**Update:It is not just the Admin role which is not working - it seems any route which required authorisation is returning a 401.**

I want to create an admin role to control access to my AdminController. My stack is MongoDb/.NET Core(3.1) for the API/ Angular 9 front end.

I seed my database with the roles

```
        private static void SeedRoles(RoleManager<MongoRole> roleManager)
        {
            if (!roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("User").Result)
            {
                MongoRole role = new MongoRole();
                role.Name = "User";
                IdentityResult roleResult = roleManager.
                CreateAsync(role).Result;
            }


            if (!roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin").Result)
            {
                MongoRole role = new MongoRole();
                role.Name = "Admin";
                IdentityResult roleResult = roleManager.
                CreateAsync(role).Result;
            }
        }
```

In another seed method I've added the following 2 roles to my user account

```
                    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User").Wait();
                    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Wait();
```

In my startup file I've configured my mongo identity provider

```
services.AddIdentityMongoDbProvider<AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo.Model.MongoUser, AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo.Model.MongoRole>(identityOptions =>
            {
                identityOptions.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                identityOptions.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                identityOptions.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                identityOptions.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                identityOptions.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            }, mongoIdentityOptions => {
                mongoIdentityOptions.ConnectionString = **REMOVED CONN STR FROM HERE**;
            });
```

My login method in the user controller gets the roles from my user and adds them to a claim list - as far as I'm aware this is so it can be included within the token which can be checked for roles. When I debugged and added a break point on this method it was clear that the roles are being added to the claimList - so I'm not sure the problem is there.

```
 // POST api/user/login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginEntity model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    string key = model.UserName + "ezgig321";
                    var appUser = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.UserName == model.UserName);
                    var issuer = "ezgig";
                    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser);
                    var claimList = new List<Claim>();
                    foreach (var role in roles)
                    {
                        var roleClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role);
                        claimList.Add(roleClaim);
                    }
                    claimList.Add(new Claim("username", model.UserName));

                    //var token = AuthenticationHelper.GenerateJwtToken(model.Email, appUser, _configuration);
                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, //Issure    
                                    issuer,  //Audience    
                                    claimList,
                                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                                    signingCredentials: credentials);

                    var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

                    var rootData = new LoginResponse(encodedJwt, appUser.UserName);
                    return Ok(rootData);
                }
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Bad Credentials");
            }
            string errorMessage = string.Join(", ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
            return BadRequest(errorMessage ?? "Bad Request");
        }
```

Yet when I use the JWT returned from logging in to my account with the admin role - I still get a 401 unauthorised when I'm trying to access this test method I've put in my admin controller.

```
    [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/admin/admintest
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [HttpGet]
        public  ActionResult AdminTest()
        {
            return Ok("you seem to have admin authorisation");
        }
```

[image: Getting a 401 using postman]

Comment: The connection for the client to server is using TLS for authentication.  The default TLS version has to be either 1.2/1.3.  Old code before June this years was allowed to use 1.0/1.1.  See following for setting TLS 1.2 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60863817/explicitly-set-tlsv1-2-in-httpclient-request-in-angular

Comment: Is this a setting I would need to change on the client (angular) code? Because I'm getting to 401's when I'm using postman - excluding the client from the process altogether

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where Postman is getting setting.  I suspect it is from your Browser settings.  The version of TLS is inside you browser settings.  Try changing the settings to disable1.0/1.1 (and SSL) and use only 1.2/1.3.

Comment: I've tried that but still getting 401 - also I've realised I'm not just getting 401 for the admin policy, but any routes which require authorisation at all

Comment: How long before the error occurs?  If it is 30 seconds you may be looking for a proxy and the 30 seconds indicates the proxy is timing out.  You can set proxy to null (client.Proxy = null).  Is your URL using HTTP or HTTPS? Try both.  Get Postman working before trying with c#.

Comment: It's more or less instantaneous - I think maybe it might be something to do with how I've set up the auth in the Startup file. I also don't have a great understanding of how the API is checking the token for the roles - so I may have missed something there

Comment: The roles are on the server. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was just stupidity which caused this error. I'd hardcoded in the issuer and JWT key variables of the Register/Login end point, and I'd wrote them in incorrectly.

Because they then didn't match with the issuer/jwt key in the startup.cs file(see below)...

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                //Set default Authentication Schema as Bearer
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme =
                           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme =
                           JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters =
                       new TokenValidationParameters
                       {
                           ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                           ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                           IssuerSigningKey =
                        new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"])),
                           ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                       };
            });
```

This meant that the JWT keys were being rejected as invalid. Sorry if anyone wasted any time on this.